Can a compact manifold with boundary be homotopy equivalent to its boundary?
Let $(M, \partial M)$ be a compact manifold with boundary, and assume that $\partial M$ is connected. I know that $M$ cannot retract onto $\partial M$. But can $M$ be homotopy equivalent to $\partial M$?
EDIT: Assume $M$ to be orientable.

Möbius band ${}$

@user8268 Perhaps you should turn this into an answer :)

@user8268 Could you please elaborate? Simple attempt to project Möbius band to mid-line seems to result in map $S^1\to S^1$ of degree 2, which is not homotopic to identity. I thought that boundary with manifold constitute cofibration pair and any homotopy equivalence should result in deformation retract.

@dsh read the question again :)

@user8268 Thanks! I forgot to say that I assume $M$ to be orientable.

@user8268 Oo, I see)

What happens to the long exact homology sequence of the pair?

@TedShifrin Perhaps I am missing something, but I think this only shows the inclusion map cannot induce a homotopy equivalence. Does it imply that a homotopy equivalence cannot be induced by other maps as well?

Good point, but you would still have isomorphic homology groups at each level.

No,
$\newcommand{\bdry}{\partial}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}$
if $M$ is compact, orientable and $\bdry M$ is connected,
then $M$ cannot be homotopy equivalent to $\bdry M$.
In fact, much more is true:

Proposition: Let $M$ be a compact, connected, orientable manifold-with-boundary
of dimension $n+1$.
Suppose that $M$ has the homotopy type of a closed, connected,
orientable manifold $X$ of dimension $n$.
Then $\bdry M$ has two connected components.

In particular, if $\bdry M$ is connected then $M$ does not have the homotopy type
of a closed, connected, orientable manifold of dimension $n$.
Note that the proposition is false if we allow $M$ to be non-orientable, as the example
of the Möbius strip shows.
It is also false if we allow the manifold $X$ to have dimension less than $n$,
since we can take $M = X \times D^k$, where $D^k$ is the closed disk
of dimension $k$ and $k > 1$.
Proof of the proposition: This is an application of Poincaré duality.
We use $\Z$ coefficients throughout.
Let $[M] \in H_{n+1}(M, \bdry M)$
be a relative fundamental class.
Then we have the Poincaré-Lefschetz duality isomorphism:
\begin{align*}
L: H^{k}(M, \bdry M) &\xrightarrow{\iso} H_{n+1-k}(M) \\
\eta \quad &\mapsto \quad \eta \cap [M]
\end{align*}
Moreover, since $M$ has the homotopy type of a closed, connected, orientable manifold of dimension $n$, we have a class $A \in H_n(M) \iso \Z$
which induces a Poincaré duality isomorphism:
\begin{align*}
P: H^k(M) &\xrightarrow{\iso} H_{n-k}(M) \\
\eta \quad &\mapsto  \quad \eta \cap A
\end{align*}
Let $\alpha \in H^1(M, \bdry M)$ be the Poincaré-Lefschetz dual of $A$, that is $\alpha$ is the class that satisfies
$$
\alpha \cap [M] = A.
$$
Let $\overline{\alpha} \in H^1(M)$ be the image of $\alpha$ by the
map $H^1(M, \bdry M) \to H^1(M)$.
Claim: $\overline{\alpha} = 0$.
Proof of claim:
Since $P$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that $P(\overline{\alpha}) = 0$.
We compute:
\begin{align*}
P(\overline{\alpha}) 
&= \overline{\alpha} \cap A  &\text{by definition of } P\\
&= \overline{\alpha} \cap( \alpha\cap [M] )  &\text{by definition of } \alpha\\
&= (\overline{\alpha} \cup \alpha) \cap [M]  &\text{see }\heartsuit\\
&= (\alpha \cup \alpha) \cap [M] \\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
since $\alpha \cup \alpha = 0$ for any (relative) class of degree $1$.
$\heartsuit$: this is an elementary property of the cap and cup products. See for example
Theorem 5.2 of Chapter VI of the book Topology and Geometry by Bredon.
$\square$
Consider now the long exact sequence in cohomology (with $\Z$ coefficients)
of the pair $(M, \bdry M)$:
$$
0 \to H^0(M) \to H^0(\bdry M) \to H^1(M, \bdry M) \to H^1(M)
$$
By Poincaré-Lefschetz duality, we have $H^1(M, \bdry M) \iso H_n(M) \iso \Z$,
generated by $\alpha$. Moreover, by the claim the image of $\alpha$ in $H^1(M)$ is zero.
Therefore, the above sequence reduces to an exact sequence
$$
0 
\to \underbrace{H^0(M)}_{\iso \Z} 
\to H^0(\bdry M) 
\to \underbrace{H^1(M, \bdry M)}_{\iso \Z} 
\to 0
$$
We conclude that $H^0(\bdry M) \iso \Z \oplus \Z$, hence $\bdry M$ has two connected
components. $\square$
Remark: it would be possible to write down a more "geometric" proof
by reformulating the above proof in terms of intersection theory. But I will adhere to the motto:
"Think with intersections, prove with cup products"!

Thanks! This is very clear.
